# if statement not working with intval

Tags: php, steam

Code:

```
<?php

$url = "http://steamcommunity.com/id/SmokeySYT/inventory/json/730/2";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

?><div class="deposit_box"><?php
    foreach($json->rgDescriptions as $value => $v) {
        if ($v->tradable === 1) {
            $url2 = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&market_hash_name=" . $v->market_hash_name;
            $url2 = str_replace(" ", "%20", $url2);
            $json2 = json_decode(file_get_contents($url2), true);
            if ($json2["success"] == true OR !empty($json)) {
                $json2["median_price"] = str_replace("$", "", $json2["median_price"]);
                $number = floatval($json2["median_price"]);
                if ($number > 0.30) {
                    echo "it worked.";
                } else {
                    echo "it didn't work.";
                }
            } else {
                die("rip");
            }
            $name = $v->market_hash_name;
            $icon_url = $v->icon_url;
            ?>
            <div class="img__wrap">
                <img class="img__img" src="http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/<?=$icon_url?>" />
                <div class="img__description_layer">
                    <p class="img__description"><?= $name ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        } else {

        }
    }

?>
</div>
```

Here you can see it working:

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/z7dd-2c0h

so there is the variable $json2["median_price"] which is a string, i tried to put it in an if statement in alot of different ways but i can't get it working so my if statement checks if the value in the string is more than 0.30 even though i tried to do it with intval() in alot of different ways.

(the value of $json2["median_price"] is different for every image, and there is one image with value 0.39 but it still says "it didn't work".)

Comment: Delete non-relevant code (eg. css styles) and put the code here.

Comment: Can you please show us the form of the string, also you're using intval, but 0.30 is not an int. It's a float since it has a decimal point. Try using floatval() instead.

Comment: tried doing it with floatval, but i still get it didn't work, also how do you mean the form of the string?

Comment: I see you using str_replace to sanitize the string of dollar signs for example. Echo some of the values after you've done something with them. It'll help understand the current state of the value. Echo $json2["median_price"] for example when you know the actual value, you'll understand why the IF statement isn't working.

Comment: i updated the code a little bit so now you can see all  the values after i've done something with them: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/z7dd-2c0h

Comment: `intval` converts to an integer. Comparing it to `0.30` looks silly to me. If you are looking to extract the price of an item you should use `floatval`. 
Or if you're looking to find if the price is above zero (0) you should just compare it with zero.

Comment: i tried it a few more times and now it is working all the sudden, thanks adrian7 and Niels for floatval() that probably fixed it.

Comment: Can you `var_dump` the value before and after you use the `floatval` function? Seeing what the value actually becomes will show why it is failing.